# Telerik BatchEditCommand not working properly

Tags: javascript, c#, telerik

The problem here is sometimes it will not trigger RadGrid1_BatchEditCommand. Please help.

I have codes below at javascript:

```
var grid = $find("<%=RadGrid1.ClientID %>");
var batchManager1 = grid.get_batchEditingManager();
var hasChanges = batchManager1.hasChanges(grid.get_masterTableView());
if(hasChanges) {

    grid.get_batchEditingManager().saveChanges(grid.get_masterTableView());
}
else{

args.set_cancel(true);`

window.close();

}
```

I have code below at code behind:

```
protected void RadGrid1_BatchEditCommand(object sender, GridBatchEditingEventArgs e)
{

    enter code here

}
```

Comment: My telerik version is Telerik UI for ASP.NET AJAX Q2 2016

Answer (score 0):

I do this in my case.

```
var grid = $find("<%=RadGrid1.ClientID %>");
var batchManager1 = grid.get_batchEditingManager();
grid.get_batchEditingManager().saveChanges(grid.get_masterTableView());
```